# Approximating asymmetric matrix's Ky Fan norm

Tags: normed-spaces, svd

Given an N-by-N asymmetric matrix $M$

Is there any theory about approximating $M$'s Ky Fan k-norm $|| M ||_k$
using $\frac {(M+M^T)}{2}$'s Ky Fan k-norm $|| \frac {(M+M^T)}{2} ||_k$?

**UPDATE**: Consider another symmetric matrix $S$

if $M=S+E$ can one approximate $||M||_k$ by $||S||_k$?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if there is any such approximation. Consider $M=\begin{pmatrix}0&\lambda\\-\lambda&0\end{pmatrix}\oplus0_{n-2}$ for instance. Its singular values are $1, 1, 0, \ldots, 0$ and hence its Ky-Fan $k$-norm is $\lambda$ when $k=1$ and $2\lambda$ when $k\ge2$. However, the singular values and and Ky-Fan $k$-norms of $(M+M^T)/2$ are constantly zero. You cannot generate any meaningful approximation of the Ky-Fan $k$-norms of $M$ from these zeroes.

Comment: Sorry maybe I haven't completely think through the whole problem. I have updated the problem, how about the new statement?

Comment: @Rein If we take $S=(M+M^T)/2$. Then the example in my answer shows that $S$ is not helpful. If we take an arbitrary $S$, then your question becomes: can we well approximate the Ky-Fan $k$-norm of a general matrix $M$ by the Ky-Fan $k$-norm of an arbitrary symmetric matrix $S$? As $M$ and $S$ are unrelated, I think the answer is hardly "yes".